# ajax - onchange event only working when clicking out of field

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am looking for something that will filter the results as the users types not just when the user clicks out of the field which is how it is working now. I added the live and autocomplete but that was not producing the results I wanted.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#submit").live('change.autocomplete', function() { 
        // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
        var thissearch = $('#thissearch').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/searchinventorytest.php?",
            data: "thissearch="+ thissearch,
            success: function(data){
                $('div.success').fadeIn();
                $('div.success').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer from facebook, thought I would share. I needed the "on" and "keyup"

```
$("form#submit").on('keyup', function() { 
        // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
        var thissearch = $('#thissearch').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/searchinventorytest.php?",
        data: "thissearch="+ thissearch,
        success: function(data){
        $('div.success').fadeIn();
        $('div.success').html(data);
        }
        });
        return false;
        });
});
```